# Akka http vs Lagom

Tags: akka-http, lagom

Please help in understanding
1)Choosing Akka http vs Lagom for building a microservice
2)Is there any difference between REST API and Akka http/Lagom based microservice.

Thanks

Answer (score 22):

This is a very broad question, but let me give you some pointers.

1) [Akka](http://akka.io) is a library (or, as the Akka team calls it, a toolkit), while [Lagom](https://www.lagomframework.com) is a framework. What's the difference? To quote [Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/InversionOfControl.html):

> A **library** is essentially a set of functions that you can call, these
>   days usually organized into classes. [..]
>
> A **framework** embodies some abstract design, with more behavior built
>   in.

Akka gives you everything you need to write a [reactive](http://www.reactivemanifesto.org) microservice *if you know what you're doing*. Lagom *tells you*, to some extend, *how to write a reactive microservice*. For example it prescribes a certain project structure, and provides ready-made implementations for common patterns in microservices, such as service lookup, circuit breakers, asynchronous messaging, and even event sourcing and CQRS. You can do all this with Akka as well (in fact, that's what Lagom uses underneath), but you'll end up implementing a lot if it yourself. If you're not very experienced with Akka (and you probably aren't, otherwise you wouldn't be asking the question), I would recommend you give Lagom a shot.

2) A microservice is an application that is concerned with one business capability, and interacts with other microservices to form a functional system. [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) is an architectural style for accessing and manipulating resources. These are completely independent, you can do microservices without REST, and REST without microservices. But you can also combine them, i.e. build your microservice as a REST service. This, or more specifically REST over HTTP and using JSON, is very common for public-facing microservices that don't only interact with other microservices, but are called from web front-ends or arbitrary client applications. So yes, there is a difference, in fact they have nothing to do with each other, but you can use Lagom (or Akka HTTP) to build a REST API.

Comment: Thank lutzh. I will try Lagom to get started.